# how to hide contents in my webapps

Tags: java, configuration, jetty, hide

I'm using jetty (7.6.6.v20120903) locally and my web content folders in webapps like as below.

```
└─webapps
    └─myWebContents
        ├─secret
        │  ├─data
        │  ├─key
        │  ├─cert
        │  └─db
        └─WEB-INF
            ├─html
            └─lib
```

So I really want to hide the secret folder from clients (web browser) but turned dirAllowed in webdefalut.xml (in etc folder)  into false dosen't work.
It's possible to see them when clients access directly to secret files.
(ie `http://addres:port/myWebContents/secret/data/myData.dat`)

Dose anyone know how to hide them on jetty?

Answer (score 0):

you should put those secret files inside your WEB-INF/ directory

Comment: I wodld have done your answer,but now that I have deployed my product on a lan.<br/>so I'm trying to manage  hiding them from others without any effects.<br/>One solution idea will be flashed into my mind that web.xml will be added as below.<br/><servlet><br/><servlet-name>ErrorServlet</servlet-name><br/><servlet-class>my.test.myErrorServlet</servlet-class><br/></servlet><br/><servlet-mapping><br/><servlet-name>ErrorServlet</servlet-name><br/><url-pattern>/secret/*</url-pattern><br/></servlet-mapping><br/>it's gonna hide them i assume.what do you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
(I did comment on Mr Jesse Mcconnell's answer. But it couldn't be formed as my expectation...)
I wodld have done your answer,but now that I have deployed my product on a lan.
So I'm trying to manage  hiding them from others without any effects.
One solution idea will be flashed into my mind that web.xml will be added as below.

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErrorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.test.myErrorServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/secret/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

It's gonna hide them I assume. so what do you think about that?